# Cannot access WL Console after upgrading to WL 6.1.0.1 (fixpack)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

We upgraded our AIX Environment from WL 6.1.0 to 6.1.0.1 without stopping the WL Server (ApplicationCenter is not installed in this WAS Profile). We have WAS 8 in Netowrk Deployment Configuration.

Installation Manager installed it successfully, then we reboot the server and we got this trying accessing the console:

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console
>   initialization failed.Logged Exception:
>   com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSourceException:
>   FWLSE0194E: Worklight server cannot be started because of failure
>   while getting a connection from data-source bound to resource
>   reference: jdbc/WorklightDS. Make sure the database is up, the
>   credentials are correct and the driver is available for the server.
>   [project buytec_worklight]

I searched the right way to upgrade and I saw that we should have stopped the server than we should follow this procedure:
[http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc%2Fdevenv%2Fc_upgrade_to_srvr610_upgrading_wl_console_upgrade_console.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr610_upgrading_wl_console_upgrade_console.html)

But at first, with WL 6.1.0 we didn't use the ant-task to deploy the console, we just put the .war found in the Eclipse Studio with the right plugin, so now i cannot manage to understand how to upgrade the console manually.

Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply re-add the .jar files driver for db2, checking that they are resolved, set again the Data sources JDBC, uploaded a new console.war created with eclipse and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "upgrade the console manually". The Worklight Console is part of the .war file you deploy to the application server, but the console doesn't have anything to do with the connection to the database.

If you want to "upgrade the console", you actually mean that you want to update the .war file, so deploy a .war file that was generated using Worklight Studio 6.1.0.1.

You can also follow the manual upgrade instructions for 6.1.0.1: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr610_addl_info_manual_app_srvr_upgrade.html

Because you didn't properly start the upgrade process, I suggest that you will take the time to review all upgrade topics, from the start: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr610_in_production_env.html

In addition, it doesn't matter how you first installed 6.1.0.0, you can still use either Ant or manual upgrading.